# What is BindingFlags.InvokeMethod meant for?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following code used to avoid a `switch` statement to decide which method to invoke, and it works with just the BindingFlags flags I have set, without `InvokeMethod`.  What is `InvokeMethod` actually meant for and why is it not needed in the following code:

```
public enum PublishMethods
{
    Method1,
    Method2,
    Method3
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvokePublishMethod(PublishMethods.Method2);
}
private void InvokePublishMethod(PublishMethods publishMethod)
{
    var publishMethodsType = this.GetType();
    var method = publishMethodsType.GetMethod("Publish" + publishMethod, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    method.Invoke(this, null);
}
private void PublishMethod2()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Method2!");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InvokeMethod` isn't used by `GetMethod`, but it is used when you pass a `BindingFlags` to [`Type.InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx).

[`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) is a strange kind of enum that combines three separate pieces of functionality (according to MSDN, 'accessibility', 'binding argument' and 'operation'). These three pieces of functionality don't make sense wherever a `BindingFlags` parameter is needed.

Comment: Aah, so I don't need `GetMethod` to invoke it, just `InvokeMethod`.  Nice!  In this case, however, I prefer `GetMethod` first so I can construct an error message if the method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) the `InvokeMethod` member:

> Specifies that a method is to be invoked. This must not be a constructor or a type initializer.

It's used by the [`InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember.aspx) method.